# Commands output prints on terminal and stdout is empty. How i can store the output or redirect to stdout?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, io-redirection, fastboot

I have a python program with following line of code. Host OS: Windows

```
output = subprocess.Popen("fastboot -s " + deviceId + " getvar slot-count",
                              shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = output.communicate(timeout=600)
```

It prints out the output on console and stdout is empty. How i can redirect output to stdout or store it in variable?

I have tried redirecting to a file but any continuation of command with ">" , "|" to redirect is passed on to fastboot program as argument and runs into error.

I have tried suprocess.Popen stdout argument as tempfile to check if subprocess.PIPE is not able to buffer.

i have tried os.system(fastboot -s " + deviceId + " getvar slot-count > output.txt"), output.txt is empty.

Comment: Are you sure that fastboot sends its output to stdout?

Comment: No, surely it does not send it to stdout. I am looking for ways to redirect it to stdout

Comment: You are not redirecting anything in your code. You should probably review the documentation for the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your `fastboot` program writes to `stderr` rather than `stdout`. Test it like this:

```
fastboot PARAMETERS > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

and inspect the files `stdout.txt` and `stderr.txt`. If the output is in `stderr.txt` change your `subprocess()` call accordingly.

Comment: yeah it was giving it to stderr. Thanks

Comment: this works

output = subprocess.Popen("fastboot -s " + deviceId + " getvar slot-count",
                              shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = output.communicate(timeout=600)
return int(re.match(r".*slot-count:\s*(\d).*", stderr).group(1))